# NameError: name 'METHOD_NAME' is not defined Python Unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I've got the following project structure:
[image]

The code for each of the files are as follows (nothing is included in **init**.py):

***my_sum.py***

```
from service import calculate_sum

def main():
    calculate_sum.create_sum()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

***calculate_sum.py***:

```
def calculate(arg):
    total = 0
    for val in arg:
        total += val
    return total

def create_sum():
    print("hello")
    total = calculate([5, 5])
    print(total)
```

***test_sum.py:***

```
import unittest

from dir import *

class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_list_int(self):
        """
        Test that it can sum a list of integers
        """
        data = [1, 2, 3]
        result = calculate(data)
        self.assertEqual(result, 6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see, this is a very simple program that calculates the sum of a list. **Note:** I am mimicking a larger project hence why I've got multiple (rather unnecessary) calls to methods.

When I run `python -m unittest discover -s test/` from the `MainDir` directory, I get an error:

> testsum.py", line 11, in test_list_int
>       result = calculate(data) NameError: name 'calculate' is not defined

However, if I change the "calculate" method to "sum" (i.e. the below), my test runs fine. **Note:** I should note that I copied this example from a site online, and therefore, I think "sum" is defined somewhere, but I'm not really sure where and therefore don't know why the error is occurring.

Changing ***calculate_sum.py*** to the below passes the test:

```
def sum(arg):
    total = 0
    for val in arg:
        total += val
    return total

def create_sum():
    print("hello")
    total = sum([5, 5])
    print(total)
```

***testsum.py***:

```
import unittest

from dir import *

class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_list_int(self):
        """
        Test that it can sum a list of integers
        """
        data = [1, 2, 3]
        result = sum(data)
        self.assertEqual(result, 6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> OK

Comment: What happenes if you remove the "create_sum" out of the original example thats not going through? As far as I can see, it does nothing... At least as far as it concernes the unit-test

Comment: @monamona it does nothing in this example. But like I mentioned, I'm mimicking a larger project which is why I've got extra method calls. In any case, If I remove "create_sum" and call "sum" directly from the main method, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

`sum(_iterable)` is an inbuilt method in python. So it did not call your method, but it called the inbuilt method.

In your test method, you did not import the `service` module which you did in your main module.

Add `from MainDir.dir.service.calculate_sum import calculate` to your test module, everything should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. But I got an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'service'"

Comment: It must be dir.service I changed in answer

Comment: Thanks again, but I got another error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'calculate' from 'dir.service' (unknown location)"

Comment: Your method name is still calculate or sum ?

Comment: It's calculate. I've not included "sum" in any methods

Comment: Wait. You have a package as MainDir itself. So it should be fully qualified as MainDir.dir.service

Comment: I am running 'python -m unittest discover -s test/' from inside the 'MainDir' folder. If I include 'from MainDir.dir.service import calculate', I still get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MainDir'

Comment: I have added the proper import. You should add the hierarchical import to use a function inside the module. You should run the tests from MainDir/ not tests/.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MainDir'. I'm running the tests from MainDir/